# Are these kind of equations studied somewhere?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I have a problem of the form

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
Q_1(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1} && \\
\left(a_k(x) + b_k(x)\frac{d}{dx}\right)Q_k(x) = Q_{k+1}(x) && k \geq 1
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Are problem like this studied somewhere? For example I would be interested in a closed form expression for $Q_k(x)$.

I realize I'm being generic, but I just need some reference if there's any.

Comment: I assume you intended the top line to be $Q_1(x)=\frac 1 {x^2+1}$?

Comment: yes, i'll fix it.